# passing value to img src with spaces and quotation marks

Tags: php

img src = '$imagepath'

This command is in a loop and some of the paths have single quotation marks in name and thats what creates the problem as it truncates the path after the first quotation mark

I tried using {imagepath} but that neglects the words after the first space.

Similarly,

some start html tags "img src =".$imagepath."height='300' width ='300' onclick='window.open(this.src)"

This too neglects the words after first space.

I also tried urlencode and decode and that doesn't work as well

Comment: Give us an example of the `$imagepath` value.

Comment: What is the problem? Why do you have spaces in your image path?

Comment: And still what is the question?

Comment: consider this $imagepath='/images/Loggerhead's turle'

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` or escape with backslash manually.

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work also the code is in  a loop and i cant manually use backlash

Comment: The problem is not part of PHP but pure HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not part of PHP but pure HTML.

HTML tag attributes have to be encapsulated within quotation marks `'` or `"` and there must be a space character between each attribute.

If you need to use the same encapsulating character, ie `'` or `"` as part of attribute value then it must be encoded, in PHP using urlencode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

The `src` attribute must be present, and must contain a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces referencing a non-interactive, optionally animated, image resource that is neither paged nor scripted. [The img element](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-img-element) and 
 [valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#valid-non-empty-url-potentially-surrounded-by-spaces)